# this code replacing the html not appending the html

Tags: jquery, ajax

suggest me how should i do to append the html not to replace html in django using ajax call this code replace li tag content replaces in html page but i want to append html on every ajax call

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'chatbot/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'chatbot/css/Community-ChatComments.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'chatbot/css/styles.css' %}" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#form1").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"./submission/",
    data:{
    "question":$("#input_ques").val() ,
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()        
    },
    success:sent,
    dataType:'html'

    });
  });
});
function sent(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
      $("#chat").html(data);

}
```

Comment: Please [do your research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and check out the jQuery documentation first. Hint: [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$("#chat").html(data);`

do

```
var existingData = $("#chat").text();
$("#chat").html(existingData + data);
```

or you could use jQuery's `.appendTo()`  http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

```
$(data).appendTo("#chat");
```

or you could use jQuery's `.append()` http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$("#chat").append(data);
```

This is assuming that `data` contains HTML elements (even in string format).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) in place of `.html()`

```
$("#chat").append(data);
```

> The **.append()** method inserts the specified content as the last child
>   of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the first
>   child, use **.prepend()**).

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("#chat").append(data);` instead. Right now you're using `.html()` which completely replaces the content of `$(#chat)`.